# Composing Async Observables that have dependencies using RxJava

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I am new to reactive programming and confused about composing observables that have dependencies. Here is the scenario:
There are two observables **A**, **B**. Observable **A** depends on a value emitted by **B**. (Therefore A needs to observe B). Is there a way to create an Observable **C** that composes **A** and **B**, and emits **V**? I am just looking for pointers in the RxJava [documentation](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki).

Answer (score 1):

You question is a bit vague on how A depends on B so I'll try to give a several examples of how to combine observables.

Example - **A** cannot be created without **B** - Use map()

```java
public class B {
    public final int value;
    public B(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class A {
    public final B b;
    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

public Observable<B> createObservableB() {
    return Observable.from(new B(0), new B(1), new B(2), new B(3));
}

public Observable<A> createObservableA() {
    return createObservableB()
            .map(new Func1<B, A>() {
                @Override
                public A call(B b) {
                    return new A(b);
                }
            });
}
```

Example - Each occurrence of **B** can create zero or more **A** - Use flatMap()

```java
public class B {
    public final int value;
    public B(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class A {
    public final int value;
    public A(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public Observable<B> createObservableB() {
    return Observable.from(new B(0), new B(1), new B(2), new B(3));
}

public Observable<A> createObservableA() {
    return createObservableB()
            .flatMap(new Func1<B, Observable<? extends A>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<? extends A> call(final B b) {
                    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<A>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Subscriber<? super A> subscriber) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < b.value; i++) {
                                subscriber.onNext(new A(i));
                            }
                            subscriber.onCompleted();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking with Observables **C** and **V** so let's look at a few more ways to combine observables.

Example - Combine each pair of items emitted by two observables - Use zip()

```java
public class A {
    public final int value;
    public A(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class B {
    public final int value;
    public B(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class C {
    private final A a;
    private final B b;
    public C(A a, B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

public Observable<B> createObservableB() {
    return Observable.from(new B(0), new B(1), new B(2), new B(3));
}

public Observable<A> createObservableA() {
    return Observable.from(new A(0), new A(1), new A(2), new A(3));
}

public Observable<C> createObservableC() {
    return Observable.zip(createObservableA(), createObservableB(),
            new Func2<A, B, C>() {
                @Override
                public C call(A a, B b) {
                    return new C(a, b);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Example - Combine the last item of two Observables - Use combineLatest()

```java
// Use the same class definitions from previous example.
public Observable<C> createObservableC1() {
    return Observable.combineLatest(createObservableA(), createObservableB(),
            new Func2<A, B, C>() {
                @Override
                public C call(A a, B b) {
                    return new C(a, b);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to reactive programming, and just put together some code that may be interesting for your case

> A needs to observe B

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscriber;
import rx.functions.Func1;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;

public class Q22284380TestCase {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(
            Q22284380TestCase.class);

    private AtomicBoolean completed = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {

        final Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer> onSubProduceTwoValues = new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public void call(final Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {

                final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    public Integer i = 0;

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        final Integer max = 2;
                        while (i < max) {
                            subscriber.onNext(i);
                            i++;
                        }

                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                    }
                });

                thread.start();
            }
        };

        final Observable<Integer> values = Observable.create(onSubProduceTwoValues);

        final Observable<Integer> byTwoMultiplier = values
                .flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<Integer>>() {

                    @Override
                    public Observable<Integer> call(Integer aValue) {

                        return doubleIt(aValue);

                    }
                });

        byTwoMultiplier.subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public void onNext(Integer a) {

                LOGGER.info("" + a);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

                completed.set(true);

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

                LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        });

        Thread.sleep(1000L);
        assertTrue(completed.get());

    }

    private Observable<Integer> doubleIt(final Integer value) {

        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public void call(final Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {

                final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        try {
                            subscriber.onNext(value * 2);
                            subscriber.onCompleted();
                        } catch (Throwable e) {
                            subscriber.onError(e);
                        }

                    }
                });

                thread.start();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Having a producer of values, it just uses [flatMap](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Transforming-Observables#wiki-flatmap) to apply a doubleIt function to the output. 
To do something different, you can maybe read [zip](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables#combine-observables-together-via-a-specified-function-and-emit-items-based-on-the-results-of-this-function) if you want to have a V that is a combination of A and B.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the kind of composition between A and B that you need to do and also on how A depends on B.

Does C compose A and B pair after pair (A1 combined with B1, A2 combined with B2, etc.) - then `zip` would be the function you want. But, in that case I wonder if you could not just do that work when you transform B to A in the first place - after all I assume that you transform B to A element by element (in which case map would be the way to go).

If instead you want to create a new A for each value emitted by B (but want to combine all those As into one Observable), then `flatMap` is what you need.

If you really first need B to *create* A and then need it again to *combine* A and B, then you might want to `cache` B to save you the trouble of calculating everything again.

There are other functions that could be of interest here (like `reduce` or `combineLatest`). Maybe you could give some more details on what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for making async observables work I suggest have a quick look at this question [RxJava Fetching Observables In Parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26249030/rxjava-fetching-observables-in-parallel).

Ben (author of RxJava) helped clarify my doubts on the topic.

Hope this helps

anand