# RxJava Fetching Observables In Parallel

Tags: java, asynchronous, reactive-programming, observable, rx-java

I need some help in implementing parallel asynchronous calls in RxJava. I have picked up a simple use case wherein the FIRST call fetches (rather searches) a list of products (Tile) to be displayed. The subsequent calls go out and fetch (A) REVIEWS and (B) PRODUCT IMAGES

After several attempts I got to this place.

```
 1    Observable<Tile> searchTile = searchServiceClient.getSearchResults(searchTerm);
 2    List<Tile> allTiles = new ArrayList<Tile>();
 3    ClientResponse response = new ClientResponse();

 4    searchTile.parallel(oTile -> {
 5      return oTile.flatMap(t -> {
 6        Observable<Reviews> reviews = reviewsServiceClient.getSellerReviews(t.getSellerId());
 7        Observable<String> imageUrl = reviewsServiceClient.getProductImage(t.getProductId());

 8        return Observable.zip(reviews, imageUrl, (r, u) -> {
 9          t.setReviews(r);
10          t.setImageUrl(u);

11          return t;
12        });

13      });
14    }).subscribe(e -> {
15      allTiles.add((Tile) e);
16    });
```

Line  1: goes out and fetches the product (Tile) to be displayed

Line  4: We take the list of the Observable and SHARD it to fetch reviews and imageUrls

Lie 6,7: Fetch the Observable review and Observable url

Line  8: Finally the 2 observables are zipped up to return an updated Observable

Line 15: finally line 15 collates all the individual products to be displayed in a collection which can be returned back to the calling layer

While the Observable has been sharded and in our tests run over 4 different threads; fetching of reviews and images seems to be one after another. I suspect that the zip step on line 8 is basically causing the sequential invocation of the the 2 observables (reviews and url).

[image]

Does this group have any suggestion to parallely fetch reiews and image urls. In essence the waterfall chart attached above should look more vertically stacked. The calls to reviews and images should be in parallel

thanks
anand raman

Comment: How are you generating the Transfer Timeline chart? It looks pretty cool and useful. Would like to use it myself.

Comment: Since my system was making external calls I simply proxied the calls through fiddler. Fiddler has an option to generate network timelines. You are basically seeing that view. After fiddler has been setup for proxying requests; simply select the sessions you are interested in and then click the timeline tab on the right pane. thanks anand

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The parallel operator proved to be a problem for almost all use cases and does not do what most expect from it, so it was removed in the 1.0.0.rc.4 release: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/1716

A good example of how to do this type of behavior and get parallel execution can be seen [here](https://github.com/Netflix/ReactiveLab/blob/master/reactive-lab-gateway/src/main/java/io/reactivex/lab/gateway/routes/RouteForDeviceHome.java).

In your example code it is unclear if `searchServiceClient` is synchronous or asynchronous. It affects how to solve the problem slightly as if it is already async no extra scheduling is needed. If synchronous extra scheduling is needed.

First here are some simple examples showing synchronous and asynchronous behavior:

```
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscriber;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class ParallelExecution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("------------ mergingAsync");
        mergingAsync();
        System.out.println("------------ mergingSync");
        mergingSync();
        System.out.println("------------ mergingSyncMadeAsync");
        mergingSyncMadeAsync();
        System.out.println("------------ flatMapExampleSync");
        flatMapExampleSync();
        System.out.println("------------ flatMapExampleAsync");
        flatMapExampleAsync();
        System.out.println("------------");
    }

    private static void mergingAsync() {
        Observable.merge(getDataAsync(1), getDataAsync(2)).toBlocking().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static void mergingSync() {
        // here you'll see the delay as each is executed synchronously
        Observable.merge(getDataSync(1), getDataSync(2)).toBlocking().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static void mergingSyncMadeAsync() {
        // if you have something synchronous and want to make it async, you can schedule it like this
        // so here we see both executed concurrently
        Observable.merge(getDataSync(1).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), getDataSync(2).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())).toBlocking().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static void flatMapExampleAsync() {
        Observable.range(0, 5).flatMap(i -> {
            return getDataAsync(i);
        }).toBlocking().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static void flatMapExampleSync() {
        Observable.range(0, 5).flatMap(i -> {
            return getDataSync(i);
        }).toBlocking().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    // artificial representations of IO work
    static Observable<Integer> getDataAsync(int i) {
        return getDataSync(i).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }

    static Observable<Integer> getDataSync(int i) {
        return Observable.create((Subscriber<? super Integer> s) -> {
            // simulate latency
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                s.onNext(i);
                s.onCompleted();
            });
    }
}
```

Following is an attempt at providing an example that more closely matches your code:

```
import java.util.List;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscriber;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class ParallelExecutionExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Observable<Tile> searchTile = getSearchResults("search term")
                .doOnSubscribe(() -> logTime("Search started ", startTime))
                .doOnCompleted(() -> logTime("Search completed ", startTime));

        Observable<TileResponse> populatedTiles = searchTile.flatMap(t -> {
            Observable<Reviews> reviews = getSellerReviews(t.getSellerId())
                    .doOnCompleted(() -> logTime("getSellerReviews[" + t.id + "] completed ", startTime));
            Observable<String> imageUrl = getProductImage(t.getProductId())
                    .doOnCompleted(() -> logTime("getProductImage[" + t.id + "] completed ", startTime));

            return Observable.zip(reviews, imageUrl, (r, u) -> {
                return new TileResponse(t, r, u);
            }).doOnCompleted(() -> logTime("zip[" + t.id + "] completed ", startTime));
        });

        List<TileResponse> allTiles = populatedTiles.toList()
                .doOnCompleted(() -> logTime("All Tiles Completed ", startTime))
                .toBlocking().single();
    }

    private static Observable<Tile> getSearchResults(String string) {
        return mockClient(new Tile(1), new Tile(2), new Tile(3));
    }

    private static Observable<Reviews> getSellerReviews(int id) {
        return mockClient(new Reviews());
    }

    private static Observable<String> getProductImage(int id) {
        return mockClient("image_" + id);
    }

    private static void logTime(String message, long startTime) {
        System.out.println(message + " => " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + "ms");
    }

    private static <T> Observable<T> mockClient(T... ts) {
        return Observable.create((Subscriber<? super T> s) -> {
            // simulate latency
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                for (T t : ts) {
                    s.onNext(t);
                }
                s.onCompleted();
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
        // note the use of subscribeOn to make an otherwise synchronous Observable async
    }

    public static class TileResponse {

        public TileResponse(Tile t, Reviews r, String u) {
            // store the values
        }

    }

    public static class Tile {

        private final int id;

        public Tile(int i) {
            this.id = i;
        }

        public int getSellerId() {
            return id;
        }

        public int getProductId() {
            return id;
        }

    }

    public static class Reviews {

    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Search started  => 65ms
Search completed  => 1094ms
getProductImage[1] completed  => 2095ms
getSellerReviews[2] completed  => 2095ms
getProductImage[3] completed  => 2095ms
zip[1] completed  => 2096ms
zip[2] completed  => 2096ms
getProductImage[2] completed  => 2096ms
getSellerReviews[1] completed  => 2096ms
zip[3] completed  => 2096ms
All Tiles Completed  => 2097ms
getSellerReviews[3] completed  => 2097ms
```

I have made each IO call be simulated to take 1000ms so it is obvious where the latency is and that it is happening in parallel. It prints out the progress is makes in elapsed milliseconds.

The trick here is that flatMap merges async calls, so as long as the Observables being merged are async, they will all be executed concurrently.

If a call like `getProductImage(t.getProductId())` was synchronous, it can be made asynchronous like this: getProductImage(t.getProductId()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io).

Here is the important part of the above example without all the logging and boilerplate types:

```
    Observable<Tile> searchTile = getSearchResults("search term");;

    Observable<TileResponse> populatedTiles = searchTile.flatMap(t -> {
        Observable<Reviews> reviews = getSellerReviews(t.getSellerId());
        Observable<String> imageUrl = getProductImage(t.getProductId());

        return Observable.zip(reviews, imageUrl, (r, u) -> {
            return new TileResponse(t, r, u);
        });
    });

    List<TileResponse> allTiles = populatedTiles.toList()
            .toBlocking().single();
```

Comment: Thanks @benjchristensen for the brilliant response. It provided clarity and resolved my issue. Thanks for also pointing out the treasure trove of examples in [https://github.com/benjchristensen/ReactiveLab]. Will dig into it over the weekend.

Comment: what is the purpose of doOnXXX() methods?

Comment: @Pangea, I think the purpose of these calls it to print when the events happen, so you can see that it's working in parallel.

Comment: This is a great answer!

Comment: I think `toBlocking` is not needed for sync calls like `mergingSync` etc. It is only needed if we do some async call.

Answer (score 4):

People who are still @ JDK 7, whose IDE doesn't automatically detect JDK 8 source just yet and what to try out the above brilliant response (and explanation) by @benjchristensen can use this shamelessly refractored, JDK 7, code. Kudos to @benjchristensen for an amazing explanation and example !

```
import java.util.List;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscriber;
import rx.functions.Action0;
import rx.functions.Func1;
import rx.functions.Func2;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class ParallelExecutionExample
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Observable<Tile> searchTile = getSearchResults("search term")
                .doOnSubscribe(new Action0()
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void call()
                            {
                                logTime("Search started ", startTime);
                            }
                })
                .doOnCompleted(new Action0()
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void call()
                            {
                                logTime("Search completed ", startTime);
                            }
                });
        Observable<TileResponse> populatedTiles = searchTile.flatMap(new Func1<Tile, Observable<TileResponse>>()
        {

            @Override
            public Observable<TileResponse> call(final Tile t)
            {
                Observable<Reviews> reviews = getSellerReviews(t.getSellerId())
                        .doOnCompleted(new Action0()
                                {

                                    @Override
                                    public void call()
                                    {
                                        logTime("getSellerReviews[" + t.id + "] completed ", startTime);
                                    }
                        });
                Observable<String> imageUrl = getProductImage(t.getProductId())
                        .doOnCompleted(new Action0()
                                {

                                    @Override
                                    public void call()
                                    {
                                        logTime("getProductImage[" + t.id + "] completed ", startTime);
                                    }
                        });
                return Observable.zip(reviews, imageUrl, new Func2<Reviews, String, TileResponse>()
                {

                    @Override
                    public TileResponse call(Reviews r, String u)
                    {
                        return new TileResponse(t, r, u);
                    }
                })
                        .doOnCompleted(new Action0()
                                {

                                    @Override
                                    public void call()
                                    {
                                        logTime("zip[" + t.id + "] completed ", startTime);
                                    }
                        });
            }
        });

        List<TileResponse> allTiles = populatedTiles
                .toList()
                .doOnCompleted(new Action0()
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void call()
                            {
                                logTime("All Tiles Completed ", startTime);
                            }
                })
                .toBlocking()
                .single();
    }

    private static Observable<Tile> getSearchResults(String string)
    {
        return mockClient(new Tile(1), new Tile(2), new Tile(3));
    }

    private static Observable<Reviews> getSellerReviews(int id)
    {
        return mockClient(new Reviews());
    }

    private static Observable<String> getProductImage(int id)
    {
        return mockClient("image_" + id);
    }

    private static void logTime(String message, long startTime)
    {
        System.out.println(message + " => " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + "ms");
    }

    private static <T> Observable<T> mockClient(final T... ts)
    {
        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<T>()
        {

            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super T> s)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
                for (T t : ts)
                {
                    s.onNext(t);
                }
                s.onCompleted();
            }
        })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
        // note the use of subscribeOn to make an otherwise synchronous Observable async
    }

    public static class TileResponse
    {

        public TileResponse(Tile t, Reviews r, String u)
        {
            // store the values
        }

    }

    public static class Tile
    {

        private final int id;

        public Tile(int i)
        {
            this.id = i;
        }

        public int getSellerId()
        {
            return id;
        }

        public int getProductId()
        {
            return id;
        }

    }

    public static class Reviews
    {

    }
}
```