# Why Parallel execution not happening for multiple RXJava Observables?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, rx-java, reactive-programming, reactivex

I am new to RxJava and was trying to execute an example of parallel execution for multiple Observables from link :
[RxJava Fetching Observables In Parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26249030/rxjava-fetching-observables-in-parallel/26250237#26250237)

Though the example provided in the above link is executing observables in parallel, but when I added a Thread.sleep(TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS) in the forEach method then the system started executing one Observable at a time. Please help me to understand that why Thread.sleep is stopping the parallel execution of Observables.

Below is the modified example which is causing synchronous execution of multiple observables :

```
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscriber;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class ParallelExecution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("------------ mergingAsync");
        mergingAsync();
    }

    private static void mergingAsync() {
        Observable.merge(getDataAsync(1), getDataAsync(2)).toBlocking()
        .forEach(x -> { try{Thread.sleep(4000);}catch(Exception ex){}; 
        System.out.println(x + " " + Thread.currentThread().getId());});
    }

    // artificial representations of IO work
    static Observable<Integer> getDataAsync(int i) {
        return getDataSync(i).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }

    static Observable<Integer> getDataSync(int i) {
        return Observable.create((Subscriber<? super Integer> s) -> {
            // simulate latency
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            s.onNext(i);
            s.onCompleted();
        });
    }
}
```

In the above example we are using the subscribeOn method of observable and providing a ThreadPool(Schedules.io) for execution, so subscription for each Observable will happen on separate thread.

There is a possibility that Thread.sleep is locking any shared object between threads but I am still not clear on it. Please help.

Comment: How do you know the sources didn't run in parallel?

Comment: I know this by printing the Currently executing Thread ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, with your example parallel execution is do happening, you are just looking at it incorrectly, there is a difference between where the work is executed and where the notification are emitted.

if you will put the log with the thread id at `Observable.create`, you will notice each Observable is executed at different thread simultaneously. but the notification is happens serially. this behavior is as expected as part of Observable contract is that observables must issue notifications to observers serially (not in parallel).